# react function- infinite loop - Minified React error #301

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to initialize Cards by calling `initializeInput`. but it is getting called in loop and goes out of memory. But if i call same function on button click `Reset` it works fine.

How can i call `initializeInput` on start up ?

```
 const CardsContainer = (props) => {
  var inputNum1, inputNum2, inputNum3;
  const [inputNumber, setInputNumber] = React.useState([inputNum1,inputNum2,inputNum3 ]);


  const initializeInput = React.useCallback(() => {
    inputNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    inputNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    inputNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    console.log("Inside initialize", inputNum1, inputNum2, inputNum3);


    setInputNumber([inputNum1, inputNum2, inputNum3]);
  }, [inputNum1, inputNum2, inputNum3]);

 // *initializeInput(); --> if i include gives out of memory*
  return (
    <div class="Container">
      <Cards inputNum={inputNumber[0]} />
      <Cards inputNum={inputNumber[1]} />
      <Cards inputNum={inputNumber[2]} />

      <button onClick={initializeInput}>Reset </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CardsContainer />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: The initial value(s) of state should be given in your `useState` call. That's what the argument is for. Also your use of the `inputNum` vars and them being dependencies in the `useCallback` doesn't really make sense, it's kind of circular logic since that callback is what changes the numbers. And if you want local, non-state values within the functional component, they need to be in a ref or something similar, they can't just be loosely defined in the main function block.

Comment: Thanks Jayce. I will use initial state and will remove `inputNum` from the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Check useEffect hook to trigger something only the first time you mount a component.

Your problem here is you are calling `initializeInput` that is calling `setInputNumber` triggering a rerender and so on...